# Visual studio 2012 web: "Add new domain services" missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Visual studio 2012 express for web is not showing "Add new domain service" in my silverlight project. I installed all wcf, ria and EF related nuget packages, rebuild multiple times, but no success.

In addition, I am unable to view Silverlight Business application template.

Previously I had the trial version of VS 2012 ultimate on the same machine and all options mentioned above used to be visible there.

Comment: you do know that different version of VS offer more/less functionality, right? (hence the difference in their price)

Comment: I don't think its a version problem as these were available in VS 2010 web express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue after installing VS 2012 Ultimate.

I was able to fix it by uninstalling and reinstalling the RiaServicesToolkit and WCF Ria Services V1.0 SP2.

-Jeff

Answer (score 1):

using SilverlightApplication1.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;

```
         businessContext obj = new businessContext();

         EntityQuery<business> query =
                                        from a in obj.businessQuery()               
                                        select a;
        LoadOperation<business> loadOp = obj.Load(query);

        Grid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
```

Comment: first add edmx file for .web